# Form validation messages not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am developing a registration form for a project I am working on. The project uses Bootstrap and jQuery to control form validation and I am using the validate plugin. This is setup in an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application using C#. I have all my bundles and routing properly configured, but am having no luck with getting messages to display on the form.

Here is the form:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Registration Form</h2>
<form id="formRegister" class="form-horizontal col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-4">First name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textFirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textLastName" class="control-label col-xs-4">Last name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textLastName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textEmail" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textEmail2" class="control-label col-xs-4">Reenter email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textEmail2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordPW1" class="control-label col-xs-4">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="password" name="passwordPW1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordPW2" class="control-label col-xs-4">Reenter Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="password" name="passwordPW2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-10">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Clear</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formRegister').validate({
        rules: {
            textFirstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            textLastName: {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            textEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            textEmail2: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: '#textEmail'
            },
            passwordPW1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            passwordPW2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#passwordPW1'
            }
        },
        messages: {
            textFirstName: "The first name must be from 1 to 50 characters in length",
            textLastName: "The last name must be from 0 to 50 characters in length",
            textEmail: "Please enter a valid email address",
            textEmail2: "Emails do not match",
            passwordPW1: "The password must be from 4 to 50 characters in length",
            passwordPW2: "Passwords do not match"
        },
        highlight: function(element){
            $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element){
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-control').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties like `messages`, `highlight` are not sub properties of `rules`

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#formRegister').validate({
        rules: {
            textFirstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            textLastName: {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            textEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            textEmail2: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: '#textEmail'
            },
            passwordPW1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            passwordPW2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#passwordPW1'
            }
        },
        messages: {
            textFirstName: "The first name must be from 1 to 50 characters in length",
            textLastName: "The last name must be from 0 to 50 characters in length",
            textEmail: "Please enter a valid email address",
            textEmail2: "Emails do not match",
            passwordPW1: "The password must be from 4 to 50 characters in length",
            passwordPW2: "Passwords do not match"
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.metadata/2.0/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<h2>Registration Form</h2>
<form id="formRegister" class="form-horizontal col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-4">First name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textFirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textLastName" class="control-label col-xs-4">Last name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textLastName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textEmail" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textEmail2" class="control-label col-xs-4">Reenter email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="textEmail2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordPW1" class="control-label col-xs-4">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="password" name="passwordPW1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordPW2" class="control-label col-xs-4">Reenter Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="password" name="passwordPW2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-10">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Clear</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Comment: Made the changes and adjusted the new code above, it is still not placing error messages.  I also changed it to the form-control class instead.

Comment: I'm at a loss, i even copied your code over mine and I still am not getting it to work.  on jsfiddle i noticed you were using some different jquery files from me, is that because i'm on 2.1.1 vs. 1.1.1 that u are showing

Comment: @JonRogers see the updated demo in the above snippet.. it is using jquery 2.1.1

Comment: Something must be missing from my library.  I am using Visual_Studio 2012 and i suppose it could be an issue with my NuGet packages.  I did add in the various files that you had linked externally on jsfiddle and bundled them properly, but still no luck.

Comment: @JonRogers, you should only edit your question to add more information, not entirely change the code to reflect an answer.  By doing this, you've rendered part of this answer disconnected and irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a messages container so the messages can be shown somewhere.
Add:

`container: '#messages',`

on your js function just before the feedbackIcons and

```
                <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="messages"></div>
                </div>
```